# Find derivatives of functions with respect to $ x$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Can someone help me with these.

Find the derivatives of the following functions with respect to $x$: here $a$ is an arbitrary
(fixed) real number.

$(a)$ $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{x^4} t^3\ \mathrm dt$

$(b)$ $\displaystyle \int_{-x^3}^{a^3} \dfrac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}$

Comment: Hint : use FTC $\int_{a}^b f = F(b)-F(a)$ where $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$

Comment: This looks an awful lot like homework... let us wait a week or so before we answer. Or at least give your own thoughts and attempts at solving the problems.

Comment: Thank you! I think i sorta got the idea how to do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, let $\,F(x)\,$ be a function s.t. $\,F'(x)=x^3\,$ (why such a a function exists?), so that (assuming you've a typo in the first integral's upper limit):

$$g(x):=\int\limits_a^{x^4}t^3\,dt=F(x^4)-F(a)\implies g'(x)\stackrel{\text{chain rule}}=4x^3F'(x^4)=4x^3(x^3)^4=4x^{15}$$

Now you try in a similar fashion the other one.

Comment: Thank you! I think i got the pattern for this question! Cheers!

Comment: Good to know, @Risa.

Comment: hi, just wondering if the answer for (b) is (6x^5)/(1-x^6)?

Comment: I think that's wrong, @Risa: first, where did you get that $\,6x^5\,$ from? Second, check that $\,1+(-x^3)^2=1+x^6\,$ ... Try again.

Comment: oops, i did the wrong method. i did the integral instead of FTC. Now i use the FTC for part b and i get (3x^2)/(1+x^6). 

By the way, what's the checking for? And how do you do it? I dont get that checking part...

Comment: That "check that..." part was for you to realize that the sign in the denominator is plus, not minus. This time it is correct.